# IF Condition on Assembly not working

Tags: if-statement, assembly

Hi guy's I have this code, on assembly using the assembler FASM (FlatAssembler)

```
;REQUEST THE VALUE (1 OR 2)
mov ah, 3Fh
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 1
mov dx, valor
int 21h

;THE NOT WORKING IF
cmp [size], '2'
jmp small
cmp [size], '1'
jmp e

;ONE OF THE LABELS TO WHERE THE IF MUST JUMP
small:
        mov cx, 10
        mov dx, 9
.....


;OTHER LABEL
e:
mov ah, 07h
int 21h
```

The program does not jump to the labels already tryed the cmp [size], 2 and subtracted 48 to get the decimal value but no luck

Any help?

Comment: Many problems there. First, `jmp` is unconditional, it always jumps. Second, `size` is not defined. Third, you probably want to specify that it's a `byte`.

Comment: By changing the jmp to je got it to work... The variable was wrong was not size but valor. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just calling jump after cmp [size],'2' you should use je

```
cmp [size], '2'
je small
cmp [size], '1'
je e
```

The processor keeps track of the last operation using the flags.In case of cmp it subtract the first value from the second.Then it checks the zero flag to find whether the two values in this case [size] and '2' are equal or not.